# Pandas data frame change structure

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe for movie ratings like this:
[image]

I want to have a new data frame to have data as a sequence for each user and each item in the sequence contains a vector of movieid and its rating, that looks something like this:

```
userId    moviesandratings
1        [[296,5],[306,3.5],[307,5],etc]
```

for each user.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create new column filled by lsits and then aggregate lists in [`GroupBy.agg`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.agg.html):

```
df['new'] = df[['movieId','rating']].to_numpy().tolist()

df1 = df.groupby('userId')['new'].agg(list).reset_index(name='moviesandratings')
```

Or use [`GroupBy.apply`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.apply.html):

```
df1 = (df.groupby('userId')[['movieId','rating']]
         .apply(lambda x: x.to_numpy().tolist())
         .reset_index(name='moviesandratings'))
```